# How do I make an object scale by dragging it with a mouse?

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, resize

I've been searching throughout Google and I couldn't find a solution anywhere. Basically what I am looking for is that I have a cube object and an arrow object and I'd like to resize the cube object by dragging the arrow object with a mouse.

I've tried almost every partly done solution I could find, but to no avail.

```
private GameObject mainObject;
 private float positionZ = 5.0f;
 public float sizingFactor = 0.03f;
 private float startSize;
 private float startX;
 private float startY;
 private float startZ;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start()
 {
     mainObject = GameObject.Find("Cube");
 }

 // Use this when user has clicked on object and still holding it
 void OnMouseDrag()
 {

     //When user has left clicked
     if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
     {
         //Move the blue box by mouse
         Vector3 positionRight = mainObject.transform.position;
         Vector3 mousePosition = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, 
         Input.mousePosition.y, Input.mousePosition.z);
         startX = mousePosition.x;
         startY = mousePosition.y;
         startZ = mousePosition.z;
         Vector3 objPosition = 
         Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
         //Set the blue box by x axis of mouse and y,z axises of empty- 
         object right one
         transform.position = new Vector3(objPosition.x, objPosition.y, 
         enter code hereobjPosition.z);
         startSize = mainObject.transform.localScale.x;
     }

     if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
     {
         //Scale green box by blue box
         Vector3 scale = mainObject.transform.localScale;
         scale.x = startSize + (Input.mousePosition.x - startX) * 
         sizingFactor;
         Debug.Log(scale.x);
         scale.y = startSize + (Input.mousePosition.y - startY) * 
         sizingFactor;
         scale.z = startSize + (Input.mousePosition.z - startZ) * 
         sizingFactor;
         Debug.Log(scale.z);
         mainObject.transform.localScale = scale;

     }

 }

 void OnMouseUp()
 {
 }
```

This is something I found and tried to modify, but to no avail.
Any help will be extremely appreciated.

EDIT:

```
Vector2 prevMousePosition;
private GameObject mainObject;
public float sizingFactor = 0.03f;
Vector3 minimumScale;

private void Start()
{
    mainObject = GameObject.Find("Cube");
    minimumScale = new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

        Vector3 scale = mainObject.transform.localScale;
        scale.x = scale.x + (mousePosition.x - prevMousePosition.x) * sizingFactor;
        scale.y = scale.x;
        scale.z = scale.x;
        mainObject.transform.localScale = scale;

        if (scale.x < minimumScale.x)
        {
            mainObject.transform.localScale = minimumScale;
        }
    }

    prevMousePosition = mousePosition;
}
```

This will now work for all axes. However, a bug appears to be causing the Cube to scale up to 10 on all 3 axes.

Whereas when the code is: scale.x - (mousePositon.x - prevMousePosition.x) * sizingFactor

The cube works and scales normally from 1.0f.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track - you've just misunderstood the update loop slightly. In one OnMouseDrag callback your code looks like it's trying to see the difference between mouse positions, but they will be same value:

### The problem

```cs
startX = mousePosition.x;
// [...]
scale.x = startSize + (Input.mousePosition.x - startX) * sizingFactor;
```

this yields `startSize + (x - x) * y`, which is the same as `startSize + 0` which, of course, is the same as `startSize`, meaning no change.

### The solution

You need to differentiate between mousePosition *in between frames*, meaning between `OnMouseDrag()` callbacks:

```
Vector2 prevMousePosition;

void OnMouseDrag()
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {                
        transform.position = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

        Vector3 scale = mainObject.transform.localScale;
        scale.x = scale.x * (mousePosition.x - prevMousePosition.x) * sizingFactor;
        scale.y = scale.y * (mousePosition.y - prevMousePosition.y) * sizingFactor;
        mainObject.transform.localScale = scale;
    }

    prevMousePosition = mousePosition;
}
```

So basically, this code does 2 things:

1. Set this object's position to where you're holding down left click (I left that code as it was, but reduced it to 1 line of code,
2. Change the scale of mainObject by comparing previous frame mousePosition with this frame's position, modified by sizingFactor.

In your code you're also trying to manage when the mouse moves in z axis. How you intend to move the mouse in a third dimension on a 2d plane, I do not know - so I removed that :)

I also took the opportunity to make the code as simple and easy to read as possible. My apologies if I removed something that was needed, but I think most of the lines of code were obsolete.

I have not tried this code, please let me know if it's not compiling or working as expected.

Comment: This works great, I've attached my final code to my original question, however I found it not working as expected in a case where I click on an arrow and the cube's scale automatically blows up, I need it to start scaling when I drag the arrow. Thank you so much!